# Could Structure contains parameters?

Tags: c++

```
struct Student s1, s2, s3, s4;
Student(&s1, "Kim", "001");
```

---

like the code above, 
If I declare the structure 'Student' as

```
struct Student
{
std::string Name;
std::string Id;
};
```

Could I call the parameter like 'Student(&s1, "Kim", "001");'?
How can I use the parameter in structure?

Comment: You mean you want a pointer to a `Student`? Also n `struct Student s1, s2, s3, s4`in C++, drop the `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a constructor to your `struct` that takes the data you want to initialize with as arguments. Then have your constructor initialize the member variables.

For example:

```
struct Student
{
    Student(const std::string& name, const std::string& id)
    : Name(name), Id(id) { }

    std::string Name;
    std::string Id;
};
```

Then you can do:

```
Student s1("Foo", "Bar");
```

Or just use aggregate initialization:

```
Student s1{"Foo", "Bar};
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to pass strings by value and then move? You wouldn't have to worry about rvalue references

Comment: @Ayxan Possibly, but it will probably not make any real difference in this case and I don't want to overwhelm a beginner by adding move semantics into the mix.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
Student s1;
s1 = {"Kim", "001"};
```

or more simply like this (since you should prefer *initialization* to *assignment*).

```
Student s1{"Kim", "001"};
```

Answer (score 0):

it dont work this way, you should start reading about OO programming in C++, here a short indroduction:

```
//this is a struct, so all members of the struct are public for standart, this means 
//you can access them from anywhere out of the class
struct Student{
    string Name;
    string Id;
    //now you defined all the member variables, now you need to define a rule, what 
    //happens when you initialize a object, a constructor
    //A Construcot always has the Name of the struct in this case it`s 
    //"Student", The parameters of the function can be choosen freely
    //with the ":" you start to initialize all members, you could also do 
    //this in the brackets.
    Student(string tmp_Name, string tmp_Id)
    : Name(tmp_Name), Id(tmp_Id) { }
}

//now you can do this
int main(){
    Student AStudent("Clara", "1234");
}
```

Comment: "you could also do this in the brackets" - In this case, yes, you *could*. But that's not true for all types and even when it is possible, you really shouldn't. It's faster to use initialization compared to default initialization followed by assignment (which is what "doing it in the brackets" amounts to).

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you initialize a member in C++. The `struct` needs to have constructor to initialize members. This is how you do it:

```
struct Student
{
  Student (std::string name_, std::string id_)
    : name(std::move(name_))
    , id(std::move(id_))
  { }
  std::string name;
  std::string id;
};
```

And this is how you initialize an object of type `Student`

```
int main()
{
  struct Student s1("Kim", "001");
}
```